# Apply "exists" validation for optional field in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I am working on a project in Laravel 5.4 and i want to do a "exists" validation rule on two optional fields (only when a value is supplied).

I have tried the following:

```
// Define validation rules
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'user_group_id' => 'sometimes|exists:groups,id',
    'user_organisation_id' => 'sometimes|exists:organisations,id',
    // my other required fields here...
]);

// Validate store request
if ($validator->fails())
    return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
```

In my application, user's will not always belong to an group or an organisation. So, when I submit my form without selecting a group/organisation, I expected the validation to not execute, however it is - I am getting the following errors:

```
The selected user group id is invalid.
The selected user organisation id is invalid.
```

How do you make the "exists" validation rule to apply, only when a value is supplied? using the "sometimes" flag doesn't seem to be working.

---

I tried something like this and it appears to be working:

```
// Define validation rules
if (!empty($request->user_group)) $rules['user_group'] = 'exists:groups,id';
if (!empty($request->user_organisation)) $rules['user_organisation'] = 'exists:organisations,id';
$rules = [
    // normal required field validations here
];
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
```

Is this the only way to achieve my conditional validation?

Comment: Did you find a proper way to achieve this?

Comment: Use https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-nullable

Comment: thank you for your kind reply, but sadly, in 5.8 billable|exists showing invalid selection for no selection.

Comment: Got the idea, actually, I am getting the select data through an array and default is 0 not NULL, so I am getting that error. :D

Answer (score 1):

I normally use `sometimes` with `required` I have not affirmed/proven why I need the required with it though, so I end up with something like this:

```
'user_group_id' => 'sometimes|required|exists:groups,id',
```

> PS: Based on my little experience with Laravel, I had a similar encounter. Checking from https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules