# Validate that tags exist

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a form with tags which send as array

```
<select class="tags form-control"  name="tags[]" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

I have suitable relationship and everything works. But I try to valdiate any checked tag. I want to validate that this tags exist. My rules lool like this

```
public function rules()
{
    return [

        'tags.id' => 'required|integer|exists:tags.id'

    ];
}
```

But it display error message "The tags.id field is required" . How I can solve my problem?

Comment: Hi, can you provide a code snippet of your solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply "exists" validation for optional field in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068157/apply-exists-validation-for-optional-field-in-laravel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have `id`. Try following :

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [

        'tags.*' => 'required|integer|exists:tags.id'

    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use commas not dots when using the 'exists' validation rule.

something like:

```
  return [
        'tags' => ['array'],
        'tags.*' => ['exists:tags,id'],
    ];
```